# remove all but one element from a div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove all the elements within a div (`.shipping_address_table`) except for one table that has the class `theTable`.

I think I am using the `html()` wrong here. But it seems like this should be pretty close.

```
$(this).parents('div#wrapper').find('div.shipping_address_table').html().remove(':not(.theTable)');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#wrapper").find('div.shipping_address_table').children(':not(.theTable)').remove();
```

Comment: this'll probably work too `$("#wrapper").find('.shipping_address_table>:not(.theTable)').remove();`

Comment: Note that this will only work if `.theTable` is a child of `.shipping_address_table` and not a younger descendant.

Comment: @ExplosionPills ...which is a difficult scenario to manage besides because then you won't want to remove any parent of `.theTable` either.. but good point

Comment: I've changed the fiddle just a bit. put the button inside the container. after it does the removal, it says that the table is `undefined` when I try to print it to the console. http://jsbin.com/anedot/6/ And it won't make changes to the table after the remove with `$(this).parents('#wrapper').find('.theTable').html('<tr><td>test</td></tr>');` Any idea why that could be? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the problem you describe is but as `#wrapper` is an id, and by definition unique, you can just do `$('#wrapper').find('.theTable')` - works for me. I woudl guess possibly that `this` has changed to some other context in your example